# Adding libraries in c++ that contain multiple files

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, qt, header

I'm new in c++ and every time a download a library that is compound by many headers and source files I get a lot of errors when I compile the executable that call some functions of the libraries.

Is there a way to include the folder that contain all the subdirectories and files of the library to prevent this errors?

I'm using qt creator, Visual studio and some times codeblocks.

I have this issue with fft3, portmidi,ogre3d,(in summary all the libraries I've tried).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all: when talking about errors you should specify WHAT errors we are talking about!

All *.lib files should be in separate subdirectories which can be included in the project settings: 
*Linker -> General -> Additional Library Directories*. Use relative paths, if possible.

Then specify the libraries to include with *Linker->Input-> Additional Libraries*.

Also take care of use / ignoring the correct runtime libraries, if you use any.

Take care as well about licences: some libraries CAN NOT be statically linked if you DO NOT have the license! (Then you would have to link dynamically.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But Im talking about subroutine libraries(header files .h), sorry if I was not clear. And the problem is that the compiler is not finding all the files that header needs(most of the time the files that header needs are other header files).

Comment: To include header files see the project settings C/C++ -> General -> Additional Include Directories. There you can specify any directory to include your header files. Same here: use relative paths.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! for your help. I was wasting my time trying to figure out how to do that. Really thanks!!!!

Answer (score 1):

You can try adding

```
INCLUDEPATH += <libs path>
LIBS += -L/path/to/your/lib -lyourlib
```

In your .pro file

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But Im talking about subroutine libraries(header files .h) that have dependency on other header files, like the portmidi or fftw library.